# Removing GND cause less bright led but continue working

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, ground

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foH2Du.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U2 is a Max7219 + 2 x 7 segments display 0.56''.

Is my wiring circuit right? Btw I have some question to ask you expert.

1) Per datasheet of LM7805

[image]

in input I need to use a ceramic 0.33uF, I have only a 0.22uF electrolyitic. Could be "the same" ?

2) If I remove the GND between Arduino and the VREG, after 3/4 seconds display goes totally off. Is capacitors effect to mantain some last current for the MAX?

3) If I remove the GND between Arduino and MAX7219, the LED becom sensibly less bright, but it works anyway. Why?

Thank you very much

Comment: [EEVblog #831 - Power A Micro With No Power Pin!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw)

Comment: For micro you mean of course the MAX in my case, right? ANd for first question? Thank you

Comment: You should be fine using a 0.22μF capacitor there. And the diagram doesn't say anything about ceramic capacitors, and it even shows a polarized (i.e., not ceramic) one! The 78xx series can even sometimes run with no capacitors at all, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Felthry, indeed, the 78xx's will cheerfully run and steadily without any capacitors, the world's got mountains of cheap circuits doing just that. The capacitors are to reduce oscillations and decouple for reduced rail noise but they aren't guaranteed to appear in the absence of capacitors. With a steadyish supply and load they're fine. Like you, I wouldn't do it myself but plenty do :-)

Comment: You have to set the logic zero on the LOAD pin of U2 for MAX7219 to work, right? Try connecting it to arduino-max GND through a 1k resistor instead of arduino LOAD pin and then disconnect this GND and see what happens.